# Is it possible to add a new sequence to a blast database without recreating it from scratch?

Tags: bioinformatics

I have a new sequence and I want to add it to a pre-constructed BLAST database containing other sequences. The makeblastdb help does not give any hint on this regard.

Answer (score 5):

You can use `blastdbcmd` to extract FASTA sequences from the BLAST database. Then you can append your extra sequence to the newly created FASTA file, and remake the BLAST DB using `makeblastdb`. Assuming you have a protein BLAST database in the current working directory, and a sequence you want to add to it in `new.fa`:

```
$ blastdbcmd -db proteindb -dbtype prot -out db.fa -entry all
    $ cat new.fa >> db.fa
$ makeblastdb -in db.fa -out newproteindb -dbtype prot
```

(Replace `prot` with `nucl` if you have a nucleotide database)

Answer (score 2):

You may create a new database with the new sequences and create an alias linking the old and new databases with `blastdb_aliastool`